# iOS firebase login

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

my firebase login screen crashes when trying to login

**Here is the error:**

2018-05-02 09:39:25.937258-0400 noteCollab[2418:625945] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The link provided is not valid for email/link sign-in. Please check the link by calling isSignInWithEmailLink:link: on Auth before attempting to use it for email/link sign-in.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1837d6d8c 0x1829905ec 0x1837d6c6c 0x1008aa3e0 0x10089c0b8 0x10089cd08 0x10089b808 0x101a29260 0x101a29220 0x101a37e80 0x101a2c730 0x101a38dd8 0x101a3febc 0x1833fbe70 0x1833fbb08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

**Here is my code:**

```
    //
//  signinViewController.swift
//  noteCollab
//
//  Created by James Hall on 5/2/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 James Hall. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class signinViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!


    var isSignIn:Bool = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func signInSelectorChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        isSignIn = !isSignIn
        if isSignIn {
            signInLabel.text = "Sign In"
            signInButton.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
        }else{
            signInLabel.text = "Register"
            signInButton.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        }

    }



    @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text{
            //check if its sign in or register
            if isSignIn{
                //sign in the user with Firebase
                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: pass) { (user, error) in
                    // check that user isnt nil
                    if error != nil{
                        print("cant sign in user")
                    }else{

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)

                    }
                }
            }else{
                //register the user with Firebase

                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) { (user, error) in
                    // check that user isnt nil
                    if let u = user {

                        //user is found, go to home
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)

                    }else{
                        //error: check error and show message
                    }
                }

            }
        }



    }



}
```

Comment: Have you enabled email login in auth methods in firebase console?

Comment: yes I have and im using the same login and password I used when register to sign in with

Comment: Why are you using signIn(withEmail, link) instead of password?

Comment: I was trying to use only email and password thanks Adeel you really helped me

Comment: Happy to help 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sign in code is looking for an email link instead of a password. Simply change the word "link:" to "password:" and you should be all set.

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, **password**: password)

Comment: glad I could help!